# Why won't Ubuntu 12.10 install?

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot, wubi

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my Dell Optiplex 960 for the past two days to no avail. I started off by burning a DVD and trying to install from the DVD, then I tried installing alongside Windows 7 with Wubi, and now I'm at a total loss. I select "Install Ubuntu" and nothing happens. Every time it seems like it's working, then the screen just goes blank with a little line symbol blinking in the upper left corner of the screen.

Any insight as to what I could be doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: What graphics card do you have? If it's nvidia/radeon try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/257917/14916 (please report back on what you discover or with more information)

Answer (score 0):

first start the window7 and run the ubuntu or wubi.exe and select "install inside windows" and assign 8 or more GB for ubuntu and also you can select more installation options.

after that restart the pc and make sure first boot your ubuntu cd and select ubuntu for complete installation instead of windows.

Also you can see various videos on youtube for better experience.

Answer (score 0):

> *I select "Install Ubuntu" and nothing happens. Every time it seems like it's working, then the screen just goes blank with a little line symbol blinking in the upper left corner of the screen.*

When you say you select "Install Ubuntu", is this the same button that you can select after the loading screen?.

If so, I would suggest re-downloading and re-burning the CD/DVD as there can be errors in the process of downloading.

You can check if the download completed successfully, this page should help:
[HOWTOMD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

Otherwise, if you pressed a button on boot screen where there are 2 icons and have been given a menu of choices, I would then press <kbd>F6</kbd> and go through each option on the list it gives you. Try to boot through any combination of those options.
You may have gotten a similar situation I had with an old desktop where I had to enable the noapic mode for it to boot and load the kernel.

After install, if you have a dual boot of windows and ubuntu, then you need to edit the commands before booting by pressing <kbd>c</kbd> at Grub menu and add the option you had to use for install for it to boot. (Image Below)

This forum should be able to show you how to automate this method above to boot into your ubuntu system:
[Edit grub.cfg](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1402197)

Sorry for no images, don't have enough reputation yet.
This is my first forum answer and don't forget, Happy Ubuntuing!